# Activity implementing Runnable posts to Looper many times

Tags: java, android

I have implemented an application in Android. There are three components: MainActivity, MyWorker and PublishService. MyWorker takes sensor's data from Android's SensorManager then broadcasts to MainActivity. When MainActivity obtains message, It will call a publish function in order to push it to my PublishService. Please see following diagram:
[image]

Below I have shown the demonstration of my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements  Runnable {
  public class PushReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i){
      Result = i.getStringExtra("Result");
      Log.d("onReceive_72", Result);
      mSend();
    }
  }

  private void  mSend(){
    Log.d("mSend_80","sent");
    handler.post(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Log.d("run_87", Result);
    handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
    Publish(Result); // publish function 
  }

  // more code here <--->

}
```

My problem is when application runs, the Logcat shows `"run_87": Result` many times but `"onReceive_72": Result` and `"mSend_80":"sent"` appear just once. For instance:

```
05-11 11:42:01.286  11631-11631/example I/onReceive_72﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:01.286  11631-11631/example I/mSend_80﹕ sent
05-11 11:42:01.286  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:01.786  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:01.946  11631-11631/example I/onReceive_72﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:01.946  11631-11631/example I/mSend_80﹕ sent
05-11 11:42:01.946  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:02.286  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:02.446  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:02.556  11631-11631/example I/onReceive_72﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:02.556  11631-11631/example I/mSend_80﹕ sent
05-11 11:42:02.556  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:02.786  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:02.946  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:03.056  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:03.221  11631-11631/example I/onReceive_72﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:03.221  11631-11631/example I/mSend_80﹕ sent
05-11 11:42:03.221  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:03.286  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:03.461  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:03.556  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:03.721  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:03.786  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:03.836  11631-11631/example I/onReceive_72﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:03.836  11631-11631/example I/mSend_80﹕ sent
05-11 11:42:03.836  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:03.961  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.056  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.221  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.286  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.336  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.461  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.486  11631-11631/example I/onReceive_72﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.486  11631-11631/example I/mSend_80﹕ sent
05-11 11:42:04.486  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.556  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.721  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.786  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.836  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.961  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:04.986  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
05-11 11:42:05.056  11631-11631/example I/run_87﹕ Result
```

As you can see, for each circle, it starts with `onReceive_72` and `mSend_80` and then produces `run_87`. `run_87` appears much than its expectation. And next time, `run_87` tends to produce more than this time. I don't have any idea why this happnes? At once, I think that happens due to Runnable but I do not know how to solve. Could you please give me proper advice, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by myself but I would like to show the answer here for everyone who probably meets this issue. The reason is multithreading which isn't managed thread efficiently. The fact is that our system can't guarantee multithreading run simultaneously.  For instance, I put some lines of code

```
private Boolean receiveResult = false;
```

in onReceive, `receiveResult = true;` and

```
if (receiveResult) {
     receiveResult = false;
     Log.i("run_87", "Result");
     Publish(Resulty);
}
```

Thread of MyActivity has higher priority so it is called much time than MyWorkerService.